# Condición if(Cursor.moveToFirst) no se cumple aún cuando hay datos en la tabla

Tags: android, recyclerview, cursor

Buen día, necesito ayuda con una app en android, en una parte donde manejo un RecyclerView para mostrar una lista de libros, de los cuales solo muestro el nombre y autor en la lista,no me muestra nada.

1ro: Tengo una base de datos llamada books,ahí inserto unos cuantos libros.
2do: Mediante RecyclerView pretendo mostrarlos en una lista donde solo aparece el nombre del libro y el autor. Es aquí donde hay problemas porque no me muestra nada.

**EDITO:
referente a sus comentarios y consejos quito las fotos y agrego el código:
En esta parte tengo declaradas 2 bases de datos, users y books, con la que tengo problema es con books:**

**Aqui tengo declaradas ambas bases**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
    db.execSQL("create table users(id int(2) primary key,name varchar(20),last_name varchar(20),email varchar(40),password varchar(16))");
    db.execSQL("create table books(id int(10) primary key,name varchar(20),type varchar(20),editorial varchar(20),año date,author varchar(40),stock int (2))");
}
```

**En esta otra parte ingreso datos de un nuevo libro**

```
private void books_default(){  
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new 
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(),"books",null,1);  
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getWritableDatabase();  
    cursor = bd.rawQuery("INSERT INTO books (name,author) values ('Quijote','Cervantes')",null);  
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Libros Creados" , 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    bd.close();  
    cursor.close();  
    createBookList();  

}
```

**Al final de esta función se manda a llamar a la función createBookList(),aqui es donde hay problema, ya que no entra al if y directamente se pasa al else**

```
private void createBookList() {
    booksList = new ArrayList<>();
    Books item;
    AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(getApplicationContext(),"books",null,1);
    SQLiteDatabase bd = admin.getReadableDatabase();
    String q = "SELECT name,author FROM books";
    cursor1 = bd.rawQuery(q,null);


    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            item = new Books();
            item.setBookName(cursor1.getString(0));
            item.setAuthor(cursor1.getString(1));
            booksList.add(item);
        } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
        cursor1.close();
        bd.close();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No hay libros" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        bd.close();
    }


}
```

Comment: cual es el query que haces? estás seguro que tienes data?

Comment: Esto que te voy a decir hazlo solo para probar, pero comenta las líneas donde haces `db.close()`. Creo que puede ser que la instancia de la BD queda cerrada... Y luego vuelve a probar debugueando

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio dylan, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento modifica tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado, saludos!

Comment: Si modificas el formato de tu pregunta, fácilmente tendrías respuestas.

Comment: Intenta utilizando `cursor.getCount() > 0` en vez de `moveToFirst()` y dime que ocurre.

Comment: Disculpen por el mal formato de mi pregunta, ya edité la misma, añado el código con las consultas de SQLite que ocupo, espero puedan ayudarme :) @diegoveloper

Comment: @Einer ya lo intenté con `cursor.getCount() > 0` y se sigue saltando el if y pasando directamente al else

Comment: Pues no hay datos en el cursor. Lo que el cursor esta mostrando es que hay 2 columnas como proyecciones pero no datos.

Comment: @Einer En la segunda parte de código que puse se ve que añado un elemento en la tabla books, asi que no creo que sea posible que no haya datos

Comment: @dylanmuñozsoto cual es nombre de tu base de datos?

Comment: @AarónZúñiga la base se llama books

Comment: @dylanmuñozsoto lo que veo es que en el constructor, debes pasar el nombre de la base de datos que dices se llama "books" pero también tienes una tabla que se llama "books" si te das el nombre es ambiguo, por lo que puede que SQLite no pueda identificar a que te refieres, podrías mostrar el código de la clase AdminSQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: @dylanmuñozsoto agradezco hallas modificado tu pregunta, agregué una respuesta, espero se de ayuda, en realidad el query que ejecutas no es una consulta es un insert, por esa razón tu cursor no tiene datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un `Cursor` con datos necesitas realizar una consulta, por ejemplo:

```
 Cursor myCursor = myDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE " + _ID + " = " + catId, null);
      if(mycursor.moveToFirst()){ 
        ....
        ....
      } else {
         myCursor.close();
         myDatabase.close();
      }
```

Pero en el caso de realizar una inserción de datos, en este caso no se obtiene un `cursor` de datos.

De hecho este tipo de operación implica simplemente ejecutar el query de esta forma sin tratar de almacenarlo el valor en un `Cursor`:

```
bd.rawQuery("INSERT INTO books (name, author) values ...........);
```

**para obtener datos necesitas realizar una consulta.**